# Pragma: no-cache in server response is affecting the behaviour of browser history in HTTPS

Tags: http, browser, https, http-headers, browser-cache

Ok, so I get the rule that browsers should not confuse history store and web cache: Clicking back should not send a request to the server. I also get that browsers manufacturers have the poetic licence to break this rule.

What I don't get is the following (please stay with me here)...

OK: Browsing our web site in HTTP, the history buttons did not send requests to server. Great! Behaviour as expected.

NOK: Browsing history on the same site in HTTPS mode, Chrome faired well but IE9/10 and FF did not. They would send the request for the HTML page to the server and then correctly use the store for the static files. Why the difference?

So after a little head scratching and testing, I found that the presence of the `Pragma:no-cache` header in the responses we were sending was responsible for this behaviour. After removing the header, that should never have been there in the first place, IE and FF faired well when using history buttons in HTTPS - no more sent requests.

Now, how can the presence of a header which should be ignored by modern browsers and only used in requests, be causing this strange issue in browser history navigation?

Comment: As always: Specification ≠ Implementation.